# ForeignKey to abstract class (generic relations)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model

I'm building a personal project with Django, to train myself (because I love Django, but I miss skills). I have the basic requirements, I know Python, I carefully read the Django book twice if not thrice.

My goal is to create a simple monitoring service, with a Django-based web interface allowing me to check status of my "nodes" (servers). Each node has multiple "services". The application checks the availability of each service for each node.

My problem is that I have no idea how to represent different types of services in my database. I thought of two "solutions" :

- **single** service model, with a "serviceType" field, and a big mess with the fields. (I have no great experience in database modeling, but this looks... "bad" to me)
- **multiple** service models. i like this solution, but then I have no idea how I can reference these **DIFFERENT** services in the same field.

This is a short excerpt from my **models.py** file : (I removed everything that is not related to this problem)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.                                                                                                                          
class service(models.Model):
    port = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class sshService(service):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pkey = models.TextField()   

class telnetService(service):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class genericTcpService(service):
    pass

class genericUdpService(service):
    pass

class node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # various fields                                                                                                                                
    services = models.ManyToManyField(service)
```

Of course, the line with the ManyToManyField is bogus. I have no idea what to put in place of "*Service". I honestly searched for solutions about this, I heard of "generic relations", triple-join tables, but I did'nt really understand these things.

Moreover, English is not my native language, so coming to database structure and semantics, my knowledge and understanding of what I read is limited (but that's my problem)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a start, use Django's [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), rather than the abstract model you have currently.

Your code would then become:

```
from django.db import models

class Service(models.Model):
    port = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class SSHService(Service):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    pkey = models.TextField()   

class TelnetService(Service):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class GenericTcpService(Service):
    pass

class GenericUDPService(Service):
    pass

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # various fields                                                                                                                                
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

On the database level, this will create a 'service' table, the rows of which will be linked via one to one relationships with separate tables for each child service.

The only difficulty with this approach is that when you do something like the following:

```
node = Node.objects.get(pk=node_id)

for service in node.services.all():
    # Do something with the service
```

The 'service' objects you access in the loop will be of the parent type.
If you know what child type these will have beforehand, you can just access the child class in the following way:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    telnet_service = service.telnetservice
except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
    # You chose the wrong child type!
    telnet_service = None
```

If you don't know the child type beforehand, it gets a bit trickier. There are a few hacky/messy solutions, including a 'serviceType' field on the parent model, but a better way, as Joe J mentioned, is to use a 'subclassing queryset'. The InheritanceManager class from django-model-utils is probably the easiest to use. Read the documentation for it [here](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/blob/master/README.rst), it's a really nice little bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, full of code, answer. With the one of @Joe J,  I'm pretty sure it'll help me throughout the modeling of my application. This site is great, its users too :)

Comment: OK, that was a great solution you gave here, especially the InheritanceManager trick, and the whole django-model-utils package. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

I think one approach that you might consider is a "subclassing queryset".  Basically, it allows you to query the parent model and it will return instances of the child models in the result queryset.  It would let you do queries like:

```
models.service.objects.all()
```

and have it return to you results like the following:

```
[ <sshServiceInstance>, <telnetServiceInstance>, <telnetServiceInstance>, ...]
```

For some examples on how to do this, check out the links on the blog post linked below.

http://jazstudios.blogspot.com/2009/10/django-model-inheritance-with.html

However, if you use this approach, you shouldn't declare your service model as abstract as you do in the example.  Granted, you will be introducing an extra join, but overall I've found the subclassing queryset to work pretty well for returning a mixed set of objects in a queryset.

Anyway, hope this helps,
Joe

Comment: Thanks really much, your answer, with the one of @Voightkampff helped me to understand model inheritance and gave a me a new way to think to my model data structure. On a side not, this was my first question in stackoverflow.com, and I'm really happy with the website, the interface, the users, the answers and I'd be glad to share my knowledge too, now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for generic foreign key relations you should check the [Django contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) (built into Django). The docs pretty much explain how to use it and how to work with generic relations.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I already checked it, but I did'nt really understand nor I could map the examples on the Internet to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

An actual service can only be on one node, right? In that case when not have a field

```
node = models.ForeignKey('node', related_name='services')
```

in the `service` class?