# SQLAlchemy: foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Let's consider 3 tables:

- books
- American authors
- British authors

Each book has a foreign key to its author, which can either be in the American table, or the British one.

**How can I implement such foreign key condition in SQLAlchemy?**

I'd like to have a single column to handle the link.

---

My approach so far was to create an abstract class `Author`, from which both `AmericanAuthor` and `BritishAuthor` inherit, and have the foreign key of `Book` point to the parent.

```py
class Author(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

class AmericanAuthor(Author):
    __tablename__ = 'american_author'
    # some other stuff

class BritishAuthor(Author):
    __tablename__ = 'british_author'
    # some other stuff

class Book(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("author.id"))
```

It fails with the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'books.author_id' could not find table 'author' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Which completely makes sense, considering `author` is abstract...

Comment: This post may help you out. Cheers! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884359/foreignkey-to-abstract-class-generic-relations

Comment: @danielschnoll it seems to me that this post makes use of a many-to-many relationship, which I'd like to avoid here. Moreover, the tech stack is somewhat different, which may lead to different answers (though I don't know what the underlying ORM provider in Django is).
Thanks for the interesting read anyway :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the `@property` decorator will work in the application it might be better to use the `@hybrid_property` from the `sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid` package. In that way you will be able to filter on that property just like any normal attribute.

Your Book class would then look like:

```
class Book(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    american_author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("american_author.id"), nullable=True)
    british_author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("british_author.id"), nullable=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def author_id(self):
        return self.american_author_id or self.british_author_id
```

Comment: This is interesting, but getting just the id doesn't give you the information of which _kind_ of author that is -- this can get confusing for two different authors with same id.

Comment: However, in this case my final table in the DB will have four columns, right? What if I wanted just title and author_id?

Answer (score 11):

I think you can't build a relationship with two different tables using the same column.

Try creating two different columns ("american_author_id" and "british_author_id") then make a @property "author" that returns the author that isn't NULL.

This way you can get the author using: `mybook.author`